# Will someone with a reputation >= 300 create a proper fish tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The current [fish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) tag belongs to a new shell. This means we need a [fish-kio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish-kio) tag. A [kio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kio) tag is missing too!

Answer (score 3):

I went with [fish-protocol](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish-protocol) (and added [kio-slave](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kio-slave) as well), and retagged instances of [fish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) that were wrong. If there's continued confusion we might change [fish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) to [fish-shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish-shell), but I left it alone for now

Comment: thanx - I don't have the reputation to help in this manner. When I do I will.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Exchange. Note that this question has been moved to [Unix & Linux Meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/). The [main site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) is for questions about unix and Linux; questions about the site itself belong here on Meta.

To request the creation of a tag, it's ok to just leave a comment under your question asking for it. Or simply use a more general tag; usually someone will come along and retag if needed.

Comment: I now know that meta is for requesting help on wiki edits (like tag creation) that I don't have the capacity to do yet. thanx